# Postfi xstatus=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.31]:25: Connection timed out)

Tags: email, smtp, postfix

Не доставляются сообщения из Postfix ни на одну почту.

Логи

```
Apr  3 15:19:42 fkoemail postfix/smtp[129727]: connect to mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.42.251.10]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  3 15:19:43 fkoemail postfix/smtp[129734]: connect to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[108.177.15.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  3 15:19:51 fkoemail postfix/smtpd[129728]: connect from unknown[10.0.0.2]
Apr  3 15:19:51 fkoemail postfix/smtpd[129728]: 1C3E54089F: client=unknown[10.0.0.2]
Apr  3 15:19:51 fkoemail postfix/cleanup[129730]: 1C3E54089F: message-id=<7d8d9a1fa7000a63a34949bcbb7d8337@api.myhost.com>
Apr  3 15:19:51 fkoemail postfix/qmgr[129722]: 1C3E54089F: from=<noreply1@myhost.com>, size=2635, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  3 15:19:51 fkoemail postfix/smtpd[129728]: disconnect from unknown[10.0.0.2] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/7
Apr  3 15:19:51 fkoemail postfix/error[129755]: 1C3E54089F: to=<Web-92@mail.ru>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.31]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr  3 15:20:12 fkoemail postfix/smtp[129727]: connect to mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.56.9.17]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  3 15:20:12 fkoemail postfix/smtp[129727]: 9DC1440895: to=<keistina1096@icloud.com>, relay=none, delay=192, delays=42/0.03/150/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to mx01.mail.icloud.com[17.56.9.17]:25: Connection timed out)
Apr  3 15:20:13 fkoemail postfix/smtp[129734]: connect to alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com[142.250.147.26]:25: Connection timed out
Apr  3 15:20:20 fkoemail postfix/smtpd[129728]: connect from unknown[10.0.0.2]
Apr  3 15:20:20 fkoemail postfix/smtpd[129728]: 124A24089B: client=unknown[10.0.0.2]
Apr  3 15:20:20 fkoemail postfix/cleanup[129730]: 124A24089B: message-id=<dfa19d0179abb3a70dafafb34fa3438c@api.myhost.com>
Apr  3 15:20:20 fkoemail postfix/qmgr[129722]: 124A24089B: from=<noreply1@myhost.com>, size=2641, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Apr  3 15:20:20 fkoemail postfix/smtpd[129728]: disconnect from unknown[10.0.0.2] ehlo=1 starttls=0/1 mail=1 rcpt=1 data=1 rset=1 quit=1 commands=6/7
Apr  3 15:20:20 fkoemail postfix/error[129755]: 124A24089B: to=<balobnad@mail.ru>, relay=none, delay=0.02, delays=0.01/0/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to mxs.mail.ru[94.100.180.31]:25: Connection timed out)
```

Конфиг /etc/postfix/main.cf

```
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/postfix/ssl/e43039d2dead7694.pem
smtpd_tls_CAfile = /etc/postfix/ssl/sf_bundle-g2-g1.crt
smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_timeout = 3600s
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom

smtputf8_enable = no

smtp_tls_CApath=/etc/ssl/certs
smtp_tls_security_level=may
smtp_tls_loglevel = 1
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = myhost.com
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
myorigin = /etc/mailname
mydestination = $mydomain, $myhostname, localhost, localhost.localdomain, 10.0.0.2
relayhost =
mynetworks = 10.0.0.2 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
#inet_interfaces = loopback-only
inet_interfaces = 10.0.0.4
inet_protocols = ipv4

# Milter configuration
milter_default_action = accept
milter_protocol = 6
smtpd_milters = local:opendkim/opendkim.sock
non_smtpd_milters = $smtpd_milters
check_recipient_access = no
```

telnet до  94.100.180.31 25 и до 108.177.97.26 25 работает, пинг тоже. Когда я открывал внешний доступ в inet_interfaces = и отправлял через php сообщение, оно доставлялось на mail, yandex, gmail почты. Через echo “Hello body!” | mail -s “hello subject!” mail@ya.ru так же сообщения доходят до всех почтовых ящиков, https://www.mail-tester.com так же дал моему смпт сервер 10\10. Но как только я закрыл  inet_interfaces = 10.0.0.4 чтобы сообщения слались по локальной сети (то есть бекенд сайт в той же сети что и smtp сервер) у меня все сообщения падают по таймауту.) Уже не знаю что делать